# Oracle 19C create database failed after installation with ASM

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I installed 19C grid, then install the 19C software only, all are successful. then I tried to create a database with `dbca` but got failed, it's very strange that RMAN failed in the logs as below, I doubt it's grid privilege issue but I can't find what it is.

more logs for this question that is before the above logs, kindly help to check it:

> [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:30:13.164 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:997] Log RMAN Output=allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1 [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:30:13.169 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:997] Log RMAN Output=channel ORA_DISK_1: SID=498 device type=DISK [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:30:13.466 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:997] Log RMAN Output= [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:30:13.631 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:997] Log RMAN Output=channel ORA_DISK_1: starting datafile backup set restore [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:30:13.633 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:997] Log RMAN Output=channel ORA_DISK_1: specifying datafile(s) to restore from backup set [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:30:13.633 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:997] Log RMAN Output=channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring datafile 00001 to +ORA [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:30:13.634 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:997] Log RMAN Output=channel ORA_DISK_1: reading from backup piece /opt/DB/oracle/product/19c/db/assistants/dbca/templates/Seed_Database.dfb [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:36:18.706 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:997] Log RMAN Output=channel ORA_DISK_1: ORA-19870: error while restoring backup piece /opt/DB/oracle/product/19c/db/assistants/dbca/templates/Seed_Database.dfb [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:36:18.707 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:997] Log RMAN Output=ORA-19504: failed to create file "+ORA" [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:36:18.707 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:997] Log RMAN Output=ORA-17502: ksfdcre:4 Failed to create file +ORA [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:36:18.707 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:997] Log RMAN Output=ORA-15001: diskgroup "ORA" does not exist or is not mounted [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:36:18.707 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:997] Log RMAN Output=ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:36:18.707 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:997] Log RMAN Output= [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:36:18.709 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:997] Log RMAN Output=failover to previous backup [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:36:18.709 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:997] Log RMAN Output= [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:36:18.728 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:997] Log RMAN Output=creating datafile file number=1 name=+ORA [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:36:18.808 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:997] Log RMAN Output=RMAN-00571: =========================================================== [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:36:18.808 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:997] Log RMAN Output=RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS =============== [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:36:18.808 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:997] Log RMAN Output=RMAN-00571: =========================================================== [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:36:18.808 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:997] Log RMAN Output=RMAN-03002: failure of restore command at 09/20/2021 15:36:18 [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:36:18.808 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:997] Log RMAN Output=ORA-01180: can not create datafile 1 [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:36:18.815 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:997] Log RMAN Output= [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:36:18.815 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:997] Log RMAN Output=RMAN> [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:36:18.815 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:997] Log RMAN Output=echo set on [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:36:18.822 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:997] Log RMAN Output=set echo off; [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:36:18.822 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:1040] hasError is true [Thread-516] [ 2021-09-20 15:36:18.822 EDT ] [RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:1046] ERROR TRACE DETECTED

```
Starting restore at 20-SEP-21
allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: SID=498 device type=DISK
channel ORA_DISK_1: starting datafile backup set restore
channel ORA_DISK_1: specifying datafile(s) to restore from backup set
channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring datafile 00001 to +ORA
channel ORA_DISK_1: reading from backup piece /opt/DB/oracle/product/19c/db/assistants/dbca/templates/Seed_Database.dfb
channel ORA_DISK_1: ORA-19870: error while restoring backup piece /opt/DB/oracle/product/19c/db/assistants/dbca/templates/Seed_Database.dfb
ORA-19504: failed to create file "+ORA"
ORA-17502: ksfdcre:4 Failed to create file +ORA
ORA-15001: diskgroup "ORA" does not exist or is not mounted
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
failover to previous backup
creating datafile file number=1 name=+ORA
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of restore command at 09/20/2021 15:36:18
ORA-01180: can not create datafile 1
RMAN>
echo set on
```

Can anyone give me some suggestion?

Comment: does you have the diskgroup created ? it looks like the DG in ASM is not there

Comment: can you show the results of "select name from v$asm_diskgroup;" (this should be run in the ASM instance that should be running)

Comment: kindly check the results:
SQL> select name from v$asm_diskgroup;

NAME
------------------------------
ORA
DATA
INDEX2

I installed with oracle and grid user for the oracle and asm, so I doubt it boz this, but can't resolve it. oracle and grid has same groups in the linux.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, the issue has been resolved with google help. it's OS setting issue, grid and oracle wasn't set as correct group, with command

usermod -g oinstall -G oinstall,dba,oper oracle
usermod -g oinstall -G oinstall,dba,oper grid

for the details please check below link

https://grepora.com/tag/dbca/

but still has issue after database created, when tried to clean and post configure, still raise error, but database can startup. let me check it and update laterly.